# Can Corvus’ glaive cut through Captain America’s shield?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

I recently got to know that the [Glaive of Corvus](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Corvus_Glaive%27s_Glaive) can cut through anything in the universe, but I also know that Captain America's shield is made of Vibranium which can absorb all impact energy, so what will happen if Corvus Glaive and Captain America are battling with their weapon head to head?

Comment: According to the MCU Wiki, the Glaive was able to stab through Vision's Vibranium body, so I would presume it could also cut through a Vibranium shield.

Comment: Just because the shield absorbs vibration doesn't mean it can't be cut. See [this discussion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184129/how-does-black-panther-leave-scratches-on-captain-americas-shield-in-civil-war/184203#184203) for more info.

Answer (score 8):

As your wiki source notes, that tidbit about his glaive being able to cut through anything is from the comics, so it isn't necessarily true in the MCU. Conversely, the same can also be said that Captain America's shield in the MCU is not stated to be the strongest thing in the universe unlike the comics. So if we're going to compare, we're going to need to compare apples to apples.

## Comic Glaive vs Comic Shield

Borrowing from the answer to [the same question over Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-Corvus%E2%80%99-glaive-cut-through-Captain-America%E2%80%99s-shield), considering the glaive couldn't even pierce Thanos' gauntlet, I'd imagine that neither could it penetrate the shield.
[image]

## MCU Glaive vs MCU Shield

Since neither has "ultimate" properties like in the comics (cut through anything in the universe vs strongest material in the universe), this one is decently straight forward, and can be reasonably determined from what we've seen on screen.

[MCU Captain America's shield is made from vibranium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwCLh-F_cdU) (as opposed to the comic's unique alloy). As per the comment above by [Harry Johnston](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5930/harry-johnston), Vision's body is also made of vibranium, and yet we see the glaive manage to pierce him. While [Vision is not pure vibranium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeDiKHjw3CY), we should still expect its strength and other properties to be present (like in Black Panther's nano-weave vibranium suits). Thus, it would be reasonable to assume that the glaive would likely be able to pierce the shield as well.

It's not a 100% clear cut case, but it's pretty compelling evidence all the same.

Comment: It is or isn't 100% clear cut? And really... that euphemism when talking about a glaive? :)

Comment: Didn't the glaive also have adverse effects on visions abilities like density manipulation? That to me suggests the glaive has some 'smart' properties that effect visions flesh (possibly designed specifically for vision seeing as he has the stone and all). It could be these 'smart effects' That cut through vision. If this the case then captain Americas shield which is just a big dumb limb of vibrainium would be impervious.